# linking server and client

Tags: ubuntu, linker, client, server

how to link these client and server programmes on the same machines i am using linux env via USB do i need to open two windows of terminal ?? and secondly i have provided the port number myself its giving error "adress already in use" how can i avoid this error and how can i compile them on same machine my hostname is "ubuntu" kindly tell in steps

```
                /*
            ** server.c -- a stream socket server demo
            */

            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <unistd.h>
            #include <errno.h>
            #include <string.h>
            #include <sys/types.h>
            #include <sys/socket.h>
            #include <netinet/in.h>
            #include <netdb.h>
            #include <arpa/inet.h>
            #include <sys/wait.h>
            #include <signal.h>

            #define PORT "3490"      // the port users will be connecting to

            #define BACKLOG 10   // how many pending connections queue will hold

            void sigchld_handler(int s)
            {
                while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
            }

            // get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:

            void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
            {
                if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
                }

                    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
            }

            int main(void)
            {
                int sockfd, new_fd;                       // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
                struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
                struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;       // connector's address information
                socklen_t sin_size;
                struct sigaction sa;
                int yes=1;
                char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
                int rv;

                memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
                hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
                hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
                hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;              // use my IP

                if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) 
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
                    return 1;
                }

                // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can

                for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
                {
                    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1) 
                    {
                        perror("server: socket");
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,sizeof(int)) == -1)
                    {
                        perror("setsockopt");
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) 
                    {
                        close(sockfd);
                        perror("server: bind");
                        continue;
                    }

                    break;
                }

                if (p == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
                    return 2;
                }

                freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

                if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
                    perror("listen");
                    exit(1);
                }

                sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
                sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
                sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
                if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
                    perror("sigaction");
                    exit(1);
                }

                printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

                while(1) 
                    {  
                        // main accept() loop

                        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
                        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
                        if (new_fd == -1)
                        {
                        perror("accept");
                        continue;
                        }

                        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),s, sizeof s);
                        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

                        if (!fork())
                        {
                        // this is the child process

                        close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
                        if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
                        perror("send");
                        close(new_fd);
                        exit(0);
                        }
                           close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
                }

                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open two terminals. In one run the server process. And in the other run your client using your localhost(mostly 127.0.0.1) and providing your same port number. if in the terminal you have already run the server program and then you want to run again the same server program in the same terminal it gies port address already in used. simply close the terminal and open a fresh terminal.